# .Net DateTime cannot be saved to SQL Server DATETIME because of precision

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, precision

I have a property on an class that is of the .Net type `DateTime`.  It is attempting to save into a table in SQL Server 2008 with a type of `DATETIME`.  I am receiving a Database Error when I attempt to save a new record to the table from my .Net service.

When I look at SQL Server Profiler and see the call to the Stored Procedure that saves to the table, the property is a string: '2014-09-04 23:08:18.0500000'.  When I truncate this string to just milliseconds the Stored Procedure call succeeds.  The conversion of my .Net `DateTime` property to this string all happens under the hood and I have no control over that.

I do not need the full precision that I am seeing in the string, but it is important to keep milliseconds.  I would rather not change my table column to a data type of `DATETIME2`.  How can I remove the extra precision from the .Net `DateTime` property?

Comment: can you add the code that is calling the stored proc? esentially it could just be formatting to the following that's required: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"` but unsure without seeing the calling code.

Comment: What is the error sql returns? I haven't had issue saving DateTimes from c# to db before... as Tanner asked can you provide some code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using a 3rd party custom ORM that serializes the data into the Stored Procedure call and I have no control over how to format the string.

Comment: FYI, the datetime datatype in SQL Server isn't accurate to the millisecond. From the documentation: "Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds". If millisecond precision is required, datetime2 is the way to go.

Comment: Your string shouldn't have 7 decimal places. DateTime doesn't support that...

Answer (score 0):

DateTime dateTime;
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

Please have @Tanner reply and mark that as an answer if correct as I believe he is correct in his comment above. Be careful to check for NULL on DateTime as you cannot convert to formated string if no data exists.

Below explains the range of DATETIME field in SQL Server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx